# Is there a way to customize a header in a Blazorise data grid?

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I am using Blazorise and I would like to add a clickable icon next to the header text (for example a help icon). I see DisplayTemplate, EditTemplate etc but a header template is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how I missed this. It looks `CaptionTemplate` might do the trick.